# Access denied for the .exe file ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Recently our group started working on an ASP.NET Core Web API project. First step was to create the project and test it if others could run it. For some reason I (creator of the project) could run the project, but others (not everyone) who I shared this repo on GitHub couldn't. Error message:

> Unable to start the program C:.../.exe
> Access is denied

For some people it helped to move the project to source folder, but not for everybody. So question I have do disable something when sharing the project so everyone could access it? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear , neither it could investigate further, please share more details and how you are tryting to access that file. You could share required code snippet related to this.